# How to get access to google analytics data API using Pentaho PDI (Kettle version 4.2.1)

Tags: web-services, api, pentaho, kettle

When I use the Google Analytics Input Step, all I have to enter is my account username and password for the Authorization. From there, the step looks up the Domain Table ID for me. So by just giving this step my username and password, choosing the id and the metrics, I am able to retrieve all of the information I need--no other authorization required.

However, I am trying to recreate this by using the HTTP Client Lookup step (with a Generate Rows step before it). I gave it the following URL, as described by http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/v3/reference.html:

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga:{*My Domain Table ID*}&start-date=2010-08-01&end-date=2012-04-01&metrics=ga:newVisits
```

and filled in the Http Login and Http Password fields with my username and password (exactly same as in Google Analytics Input step), respectively. However, when I preview the results of this HTTP Client step, the transformation returns an error that says that Login is required.

I have also tried this with the REST Client Lookup Step (with a Generate Rows step before it). I chose the GET HTTP method, the JSON application type, and filled in my HTTP Login and password for authentication. When I try to run this, it does not return an error, but in the result field of the preview output it says "Invalid Credentials."

What is the Google Analytics Input Step doing differently from the HTTP Client Lookup and REST Client Lookup steps? And how do I access the same information using those lookup steps?

I want to be able to access API's from other web sites as well, not just from Google Analytics, so it is important for me to be able to do this for any API.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I have made ​​a request to google analytics using HTTP client step, and it works perfect.

First, you need a token from Google Analytics:
https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?accountType=GOOGLE&Email=xxxxxxx@gmail.com&Passwd=xxxxxxx&service=analytics

This token is a long string.

The token is going to step client as HTTP header. The parameter must be called:
Authorization = token

Others parameters:
GData-Version=3.

After you add the request parameters. (ids, start-date, end-date, metrics, filter, segment)

You also have to add the key to your profile id, as the last parameter.

This request returns a XML. Use XML parser step to get metrics value.

Answer (score 0):

which Kettle version are you using? as far as i know there are some changes in google api

read this bug report:

http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-7942